Why do we use a slash in a group path when declaring repositories for plugins?
I created an empty Android Studio project and pluginManagement in the settings.gradle.kts looks like the following:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

1. Why does the project get built perfectly. If i look at official Google maven repository i can see that there is no slash in the package names.
2. I tried to delete the slashes and the project gets built perfectly again so why do i have to write them at all ?

The hint is in the name of the method includeGroupByRegex: those are regular expressions. And . in regular expressions refers to any character. So com.android matches the string com.android, but also comxandroid. The backslashes escape the . to only match itself. So while removing them keeps the code working, it's not technically correct, because you really only want to include anything starting with com.android. and not packages named comxandroid..

@JoachimSauer So if . refers to any character, what does * mean ? And why don't we use slashes before the second dots ?

Please read up on regex, you'll need them plenty of times ;-) * means "the last thing 0 or more times". The reason it's not escaped is probably because some packages use just com.android as the group (i.e. they don't use com.android.foo).

@JoachimSauer Yeah, i have read up on regex before asking one more question and i still don't understand :D. We have com\\.android.*. First how does it match com.android ? . means any one character, but nothing is not a character. And second how does it match com.android.application ? * means "the last thing 0 or more times", so if . wildcard is matched . character, all other next characters must be . as well: com.android.., com.android... and so on. Sorry for being stupid but i don't really get how it works )))

When I said * means "the last thing zero or more times" I didn't mean "repeat the last thing zero or more times" but it's actually a modifier: "the last thing can occur zero or more times". So .* can match 0 of anything, i.e. the empty string. That's how all the quantifiers in regex (like *, ?, + and {5}) work. And since we're at it "the last thing" is usually the last character, but it can be a group (foo) or a character class [abc].
